# Listview items appearing in wrong order

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I am having an unusual problem with my listview. I have a listview with a list of video files stored on the SD card along with a play button. When I click on the play button, a separate activity is created using Intent and when the application comes back to the original application, my whole list is reversed. I am using the following code.. (not complete code)

```
String[] vlist = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE };
    videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                               vlist, null, null, null);


    int v_count= videocursor.getCount();
    String[] videolist = new String[v_count];

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter=new MainAdapter(this,videolist, videocursor); //sending parameters to MainAdapter. 
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    //list.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this); 
    list.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

I don't know whats wrong.. Any suggestions??

Comment: Can you give more information about what Adapter you use...

Comment: please have a look at the code above.. MainAdapter is a separate class where I have used LayoutInflater.. Everything goes fine when the activity is recreated (like upon changing orientation).. Please give me some suggestions.. I also want to restart this activity so that it can create everything from start everytime without errors. any suggestions please?

Comment: @Farhan: Your `MainAdapter` is broken, possibly due to problems in your row recycling. Beyond that, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Actually I have made a separate class for MainAdapter which I haven't shown here. I just want to know what is the method of refreshing the whole activity from start. I hope it will fix my problem.. thnkx

Comment: Actually the same is happening to me, it seems to be related with row recycling but the code is apparently perfect. If you solved it, I'd appreaciate some hints. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue , and removed `notifyDataSetChanged();` in adapter class within `if-else` and then my items in the listview were in the order i wanted it to be.

Comment: Edit the question to include why you suggest that please. See [How do I write a good answer to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)